# how to compare two list of tibco queues

Tags: java, tibco-ems

how can i compare below two lists, i need to compare each parameter of the queue as well, which ever queue is missing in the destList, i want it as output.

```
List<QueueInfo> sourceList;
    List<QueueInfo> destList;
```

QueueInfo is a class

sourceList

```
[Queue['abcd',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000],    Queue['def',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000], Queue['xyz',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000], Queue['wed',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000]]
```

destList

```
[Queue['aaaaa',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000], Queue['def',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000], Queue['xcv',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000], Queue['www',static,maxBytes=524288000,expiry=7200000]]
```

please suggest me any idea or how can I proceed.
Thanks

Comment: down votes ?  Am I not clear with the question ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am stuck at this point, I was able to retrieve the queues from tibcos and really do not have any idea to proceed further in comparision logic. That is the reason I posted here for any kind of suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a class ComparableQueueInfo that extends the QueueInfo implementing the method equals properly.

Then you should create two lists of ComparableQueueInfo.
Finally you can use the code:

```
sourceList.retainAll(destList)
```

to find all the ComparableQueueInfo objects in the sourceList that are contained on the destList.

If you want to find the ComparableQueueInfo objects in the sourceList that are missing on the destList you can use the method *removeAll* on the sourceList passing it a List of common objects built using the previuos retainAll method.

I hope that answer could resolve your problem

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, I tried using two for loops , each loop traversing the source and destList respectively and ,if the name matches on both lists, I removed that name from destList. with this logic i am able to find out the left out queues in destList :)

Comment: for(int i=0;i<source.size;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<destList.size;j++){
 if(source.get(i).getName.equals(destList.get(j).getName())){
 
  destList.remove(j);
 }
 }
}